# AdWords Automated Live Email Alerts

Tags: javascript, php, google-ads-api

I would like to create a custom alert for an AdWords campaign.

AdWord Sripts: https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/

The AdWords scripts only allows daily or hourly runs of the script. However, I would like a ***live*** monitoring of the alert.

How can I do this?

I am basically trying to receive an alert whenever the budget is greater than my set value.

Answer (score 0):

AdWords statistics may be up to three hours delayed. So when the cost gets reported to you, the number may already be three hours old, and even if you pause the campaign right away, the cost will keep going up for another three hours. With that in mind, hourly scripts are not that bad.

Alternatively, play with scheduling a number of hourly scripts so one of them runs every 10 minutes, say... And have each script poll the data more than once with delay in between... Probably an overkill

Comment: the scripts that run every 1 hour only runs at the hour and not at user set intervals :(
Meaning it runs only at 1:00, 2:00, 3:00, etc.... no matter what

Comment: That's not exactly how that works. If you click 'create schedule' at 1:10, say, the script will run 2:10, 3:10, 4:10 etc. If you click at 1:27, it will run 2:27, 3:37 and so on. Thus could be used to your advantage.